# Finding Last Name Using LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to get last name using linq in visual studio. In my database, i have the Field name like "FullName".

In this Field I have value like "Subbu Cargos"
I Wanna Display the "Cargos" in my textbox.

How can i make a simple linq query?

Comment: My last name is Iftode and since in my culture the name is spelled "Iftode Adrian" (ie, last name first :)) and not to forget that I also have a middle name and maybe in future I will gain a Title, how do you deal with my name if it would be saved in your database?

Comment: interesting that you chose to do it the wrong way round for SO :)

Comment: A last name can also consist of several words separated by spaces. In some cultures you will encounter many of those. If you still have the possibility of modifying the database to use separate fields, you should do so.

Comment: @BobTodd, well we're slightly moving to the West Side so we imported McDonald's and this

Answer (score 1):

Would it be over simple to say:

```
return FullName.Split(' ').Last()
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not trying to parse out the last name. Like you say, first and last names could be switched around, someone might have a second name, or a last name that consists of multiple words (“van Dijk”), or may not have entered a last name at all.

Check out this article: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

If you still want to do this however, try something like this:

```
customers.Select(c => c.FullName.Split(' ').Last());
```

You might not be able to this on the server side. In that case:

```
customers
    .Select(c => c.FullName)
    .ToList()
    .Select(n => n.Split(' ').Last());
```

Untested, but this should give a rough idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest breaking it up into different fields - Firstname, Middlename, lastname, Title - and rebuilding the name on the fly when you come to display it.

If you're still determined to use one field, then consider a query like:

```
string s = "Subba Cargos";
var lastnames = from name in s.Split(new Char[] { ' ' }).Last<string>()
                        select name;
```

Comment: why s.Split(new char..) .. Just a s.Split() will do..Also this will return IEnumerable<char> not a string..

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it like this:

```
customers
.Select (b => b.FullName.Substring ((b.FullName.IndexOf(' ') + 1)));
```